# executing flask app as executable in nodejs child_process

Tags: node.js, flask, electron, child-process

i am creating an electron app with a flask app running locally on the desktop with using a child process.
The service is running fine, but i am unable to capture any event in child process to ensure if the flask server has started or not. Is there anyway to capture the event?

Answer (score 0):

The data event gets all of the text printed by the python script on terminal. Im using this in a node rest api to get the python script output, I think it would be the same for electron.

```js
const pythonScriptPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './executeProcess.py')
  const python = childProcess.spawn('python', [pythonScriptPath])

  python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString())
  }
```

Comment: the flask app is running  as an executable, and it will be only captured by 'data' event if python code prints something, which in my case is not happening. my flask app is not printing any thing on startup